# Why is Netflix more effecient in Safari than Firefox?

Tags: safari, firefox, netflix

I've noticed that when I play Netflix video in Firefox, my Macbook Air's fans spin up to maximum, but under Safari, it stays silent. Why does Safari cause less of a load?

Comment: I'm no Netflix user, but it may just be the engine behind safari (which is WebKit) which works better *in that context* than the engine behind Firefox (Gecko). Try using Google Chrome - which uses WebKit as well - and see if it behaves similar to Safari.

Comment: Does it use flash on Firefox and not on Safari ?

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler Nope. Netflix uses Sliverlight exclusively on desktops and laptops.

Answer (score 1):

Please see [Toms Hardware Benchmark](http://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/macbook-air-chrome-16-firefox-9-benchmark,3108-13.html).  This could help explain comparable efficiency between Safari and Firefox.  I have no proof, but a Apple Genius has also told me Firefox is less efficient compared to Safari and Chrome.